# ngTranslate with pluralization and HTML

Tags: angularjs, messageformat.js

I have a template with ngTranslate pluralization:

```
en-US "{count, plural, one{1 accepted} other{# accepted}}"
pt-BR "{count, plural, one{1 aceito} other{# aceitos}}"
```

But I want to put the number between a `span` tag:

```
en-US "{count, plural, one{<span>1</span> accepted} other{<span>#</span> accepted}}"
pt-BR "{count, plural, one{<span>1</span> aceito} other{<span>#</span> aceitos}}"
```

This way, if I use the `translate` attribute directive:

```
<span translate="LBL_ACCEPTED" translate-values="model.i18nValues" translate-interpolation="messageformat"></span>
```

the HTML is encripted and I can see the HTML tag in the final result. So I use the `ng-bind-html` directive:

```
<span ng-bind-html="'LBL_ACCEPTED' | translate:model.i18nValues:'messageformat' | trustHtml"></span>
```

Same result. The HTML is displayed to the user.

Is there any way to decrypt this HTML tags?

**EDIT:**

The problem isn't specific to ngMessageFormat use. If I have a translation like `"<b>{{count}}</b> accepted"`, the tags are escaped. I tried adding the `translate-compile` directive, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

In the module config, I was setting:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
```

Wasted a couple of hours here.